How to extract the value from a XML div tag as element value
I have a xml which appears like below and I need to extract "ABC" value to be able to map in some other place.Please suggest!
<message>&lt;div style="font-weight:bold;color:#2ee460;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:0px;padding-bottom:5px;padding-left:5px;border-bottom:1px solid #6D9DAD;font-size:12px;text-transform: uppercase;text-align: left;"&gt;ABC&lt;/div&gt;</message>
